# How to select div whith jquery from inside another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

so I have this html:

```
 <div>
 <div>
 <a class="member-img" href="#" >
 <img src="image.jpg" alt="member">
 </a>
 </div>               
 <div class="member-bar">
 </div>
 </div>
```

and i try to select "member-bar" when the user hovers "member-img"

```
 $('.member-img').hover(function(){ $(this).closest(".member-bar").slideDown() });
```

but it doesn't seem to work, any help for this code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`member-bar` would need to be a parent of `member-img` in order for that to work. You need to first find the parent, then find `member-bar` as a sibling:

```
$(".member-img").hover(function() {
  $(this).parent().next(".member-bar").slideDown();
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3tEvz/) for the above code